# How to cast this date and save to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, casting, paypal

`08:15:16 April 1, 2010 PDT` I need to save this to DateTime in MSSQL database but I can't convert this in C#. Can somebody help me to cast it? And what the hell is '`PDT`'?

Comment: how does your code look so far? what happens when you try to use a parse method?

Comment: PDT – Pacific Daylight Time is a time zone.

Comment: be careful with the timezone, that is the tricky part of this question

Comment: This might be relevant for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580356/parsing-rfc1123-formatted-dates-in-c-net-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is related to [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

I'm not sure how to get from alpha timezone to numeric, but after you do that you can

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime("Thu, 18 Mar 2004 14:52:56-07:00");
```

**Update:** This link apparently contains code to do the "PDT" to GMT offset conversion.  http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/214648-how-do-i-parse-date-w-time-zone  Also check out the TimeZoneInfo class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

Comment: I used code from http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/214648-how-do-i-parse-date-w-time-zone and I think it works fine. Actually it is important to cast that PDT to +0700 and than it works. If there is any problem I will reopen question but for now it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code in this post seems to work fine: http://www.codeillustrator.com/2010/03/converting-paypal-paymentdate-to-net.html

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public static class PayPalTransaction
{
    public static DateTime ConvertPayPalDateTime(string payPalDateTime)
    {
    // accept a few different date formats because of PST/PDT timezone and slight month difference in sandbox vs. prod.
        string[] dateFormats = { "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PDT", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PDT" };
        DateTime outputDateTime;

        DateTime.TryParseExact(payPalDateTime, dateFormats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDateTime);

        // convert to local timezone
        outputDateTime = outputDateTime.AddHours(3);

        return outputDateTime;
    }
}
```

(answer cross-posted for this similar question: [How do I convert Paypal's HH:MM:SS DD Mmm(.) YYYY PST/PDT to a C# UTC DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500160/how-do-i-convert-paypals-hhmmss-dd-mmm-yyyy-pst-pdt-to-a-c-utc-datetime))