# How do I convert Paypal's HH:MM:SS DD Mmm(.) YYYY PST/PDT to a C# UTC DateTime?

Tags: c#, date

I would like to log a payment_date in this format in a SQL Server database.

**Update.** Instinct was right on this one.  Found a solution here: http://www.codeillustrator.com/2010/03/converting-paypal-paymentdate-to-net.html, verifying... of course, if Paypal ever moves out of the West Coast, I'll be in trouble.  Is there a better way to parse this?  Maybe with TimeZone?

```
public static DateTime ConvertPayPalDateTime(string payPalDateTime)
{
    // accept a few different date formats because of PST/PDT timezone and slight month difference in sandbox vs. prod.
    string[] dateFormats = { "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PDT", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PDT" };
    DateTime outputDateTime;

    DateTime.TryParseExact(payPalDateTime, dateFormats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDateTime);

    // convert to local timezone
    outputDateTime = outputDateTime.AddHours(3);

    return outputDateTime;
}
```

Wait a sec, that code above is completely wrong for me.  I'm on the West Coast!  Ideally this should be updated to send the date to a proper UTC DateTime and handle any time zone.  Also the code above doesn't handle PDT properly (if converted to UTC).

**Update2.** Apparently, at least in previous versions, the sandbox would return "Feb." while the live returns "Feb". Lol. Someone save me!

**Update3.** Link to Regex version http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/77/Converting-PayPal-Dates-to-Net-DateTime-using-Regex, but debugging could be an issue.  Regex does not seem like the right way to do this.  There must be a better way.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a PayPal datestring into a valid .net datetime value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dateValue">a string containing a PayPal date</param>
/// <param name="localUtcOffset">the number of hours from UTC/GMT the local 
/// time is (ie, the timezone where the computer is)</param>
/// <returns>Valid DateTime value if successful, DateTime.MinDate if not</returns>
private static DateTime ConvertFromPayPalDate(string rawPayPalDate, int localUtcOffset)
{
    /* regex pattern splits paypal date into
     * time : hh:mm:ss
     * date : Mmm dd yyyy
     * timezone : PST/PDT
     */
     const string payPalDateRegex = @"(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<date>(?<
Mmm>[A-Za-z\.]{3,5})\s(?<dd>\d{1,2}),?\s(?<yyyy>\d{4}))\s(?<tz>[A-Z]{0,3})";  
    //!important : above line broken over two lines for formatting - rejoin in code editor
    //example 05:49:56 Oct. 18, 2009 PDT
    //        20:48:22 Dec 25, 2009 PST
    Match dateMatch = Regex.Match(rawPayPalDate, payPalDateRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    DateTime time, date = DateTime.MinValue;
    //check to see if the regex pattern matched the supplied string
    if (dateMatch.Success)
    {
        //extract the relevant parts of the date from regex match groups
        string rawDate = dateMatch.Groups["date"].Value;
        string rawTime = dateMatch.Groups["time"].Value;
        string tz = dateMatch.Groups["tz"].Value;

        //create date and time values
        if (DateTime.TryParse(rawTime, out time) && DateTime.TryParse(rawDate, out date))
        {
            //add the time to the date value to get the datetime value
            date = date.Add(new TimeSpan(time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second));
            //adjust for the pdt timezone.  Pass 0 to localUtcOffset to get UTC/GMT
            int offset = localUtcOffset + 7; //pdt = utc-7, pst = utc-8
            if (tz == "PDT")//pacific daylight time
                date = date.AddHours(offset);
            else  //pacific standard time
                date = date.AddHours(offset + 1);
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Which format do you want to log in the db? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: paid DATETIME, haven't tried anything yet - though this might do the trick http://www.codeillustrator.com/2010/03/converting-paypal-paymentdate-to-net.html

Comment: Note that the linked code does not distinguish between PST and PDT and therefore is going to break for an hour every year!

Comment: @tc, how do we do this right?  can I use the timezone feature in .NET?

Comment: my server is in Asia tracking time with UTC, it might break for half the year!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done any  C# since 2006, so this code probably doesn't compile. Test it before you fly!

```
public static DateTime ConvertPayPalDateTime(string payPalDateTime)
{
  // Get the offset.
  // If C# supports switching on strings, it's probably more sensible to do that.
  int offset;
  if (payPalDateTime.EndsWith(" PDT"))
  {
     offset = 7;
  }
  else if (payPalDateTime.EndsWith(" PST"))
  {
     offset = 8;
  }
  else
  {
    throw some exception;
  }

  // We've "parsed" the time zone, so remove it from the string.
  payPalDatetime = payPalDateTime.Substring(0,payPalDateTime.Length-4);

  // Same formats as above, but with PST/PDT removed.
  string[] dateFormats = { "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy" };

  // Parse the date. Throw an exception if it fails.
  DateTime ret = DateTime.ParseExact(payPalDateTime, dateFormats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDateTime);

  // Add the offset, and make it a universal time.
  return ret.AddHours(offset).SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Universal);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
 public static DateTime ConvertPayPalDateTime(string payPalDateTime)
 { 
    CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    // accept a few different date formats because of PST/PDT timezone and slight month difference in sandbox vs. prod.
    string[] dateFormats = { "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PDT", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PDT",
                             "HH:mm:ss dd MMM yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss dd MMM. yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss dd MMM yyyy PDT", "HH:mm:ss dd MMM. yyyy PDT"};
    DateTime outputDateTime;

    DateTime.TryParseExact(payPalDateTime, dateFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDateTime);

    // convert to local timezone
    TimeZoneInfo hwZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

    outputDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(outputDateTime, hwZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

    return outputDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in this post seems to work fine: http://www.codeillustrator.com/2010/03/converting-paypal-paymentdate-to-net.html

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public static class PayPalTransaction
{
    public static DateTime ConvertPayPalDateTime(string payPalDateTime)
    {
    // accept a few different date formats because of PST/PDT timezone and slight month difference in sandbox vs. prod.
        string[] dateFormats = { "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PST", "HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy PDT", "HH:mm:ss MMM. dd, yyyy PDT" };
        DateTime outputDateTime;

        DateTime.TryParseExact(payPalDateTime, dateFormats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDateTime);

        // convert to local timezone
        outputDateTime = outputDateTime.AddHours(3);

        return outputDateTime;
    }
}
```

(answer cross-posted for this similar question: [How to cast this date and save to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094664/how-to-cast-this-date-and-save-to-database/7517931))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already parsed the date with [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) (or one of the other similar methods) you can call [DateTime.ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx)

EDIT: perhaps TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc is more appropriate:
The ToUniversalTime method converts a DateTime value from local time to UTC. To convert the time in a non-local time zone to UTC, use the TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo) method. To convert a time whose offset from UTC is known, use the ToUniversalTime method.

Comment: I'm not sure I can trust my ParseExact.

Comment: -1. `ToUniversalTime()` will interpret it as a time in your local time zone, which adds even more edge cases to deal with (I don't think Windows keeps historic time zone data either).