# On converting a string to a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

Am unable to convert a string which represents date and time ex: `"Tue Mar 18 14:37:34 PDT 2014"` to a DateTime object. From the format I can figure it out to be in the RFC 1123 format. What is the best way to parse date strings as above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing RFC1123 formatted dates in C#, .Net 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580356/parsing-rfc1123-formatted-dates-in-c-net-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezone literals are not supported by DateTime.Parse/ParseExact. Here is a workaround:

```
string inputDate = "Tue Mar 18 14:37:34 PDT 2014";
inputDate = inputDate.Replace("PDT", "-7");
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", culture);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the format of the string like this (you are pretty close): 
**Sat, 01 Nov 2008 19:35:00 GMT**

You can use **DateTime.Parse(dateString);**

Find more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1k1skd40(v=vs.100).aspx